# Visual Studio Attach to Process IE COM Plugin

Tags: com, activex, visual-studio-debugging, attach-to-process

I have ActiveX COM Plugin for Internet Explorer. I want to "Attach to Process" to this plugin and debug it. I tried to attach to iexplorer.exe process but Visual Studio did not enter the breakpoint. What is my fault? Which process hosts this COM Plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `iexplorer.exe` most likely problem with something else.

Make sure that the `debug` version of the your Plugin `.DLL` loaded by the Internet Explorer process from the correct place (PluginProject\Debug) where present `.pdb` from the last build (check your Registry entry for the Plugin registration or try show MessageBox from it).

Also check you trying to debug x86 version of the Plugin with the x86 version of the IE (or x64 with x64;)